# How to create a chat view?

Tags: android, chat, android-xml

I'm fairly new to Android Studios so please excuse me if my question is silly. I am trying to create a chat window which would look something like this. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X4ii.png However I'm stuck on the actual chat part. How would I create the chat window itself meaning how would I create blocks that appear holding the message that would get displayed in the chat window. This is my code. I assume all that code would go in the listview part.

```
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:weightSum="1">
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/homeBTN"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/homebtnunpressed"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <View android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/updBTN"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/settingsbtnunpressed"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:background="#-3355444"
        android:text="YOU WERE MATCHED ON"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/matchedonTV />


    <View android:layout_width="3dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="Exit"
        android:id="@+id/exitBTN"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="366dp"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_weight="0.33" />



<LinearLayout

    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="366dp">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:background="#-3355444"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/editText" />


    <View android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="Send"
        android:id="@+id/sendBTN"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If I was unclear, please tell me.

Comment: Do you mean the actual chat messages? If so, you could just have them in a ListView and use the align property to align them to either the left or the right of the list.

Comment: @TastyLemons Yeah the actual messages. I would need an imageview for the bubbles and a textview for the values inside as well I assume?. But what would the code be to automatically generate a bubble and a textview everytime the user hits send.

Comment: You can set a background Drawable to your TextView. You can create it grammatically with an XML drawable or you can use a 9 Patch Image. But for starters just use a normal Image File. When you add an Item to the Listview like: "Hello World", if the TextView has the background Drawable set to an Image in the XML, it will automatically add the bubble :)

Answer (score 0):

for any chat view you must have a list view.and in Adapter of this list view,you check out to message is received or sent,According to this Add a view in `public void getView()`.for ex:if you know message is get received to user then inflate view of received else inflate view send.and if you are using Array Adapter then

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (getItem(position).getType() == Message.TYPE_STATUS) {
        return STATUS;
    } else if (getItem(position).getStatus() <= Message.STATUS_RECEIVED) {
        return RECEIVED;
    } else {
        return SENT;
    }
}
```

this code will help you.and for inflation of view you must have now two layout file over your xml file.

Comment: How do I create an Adapter which expects single messages